# Background images not working

Tags: css, background-image

I'm having this very annoying problem that I've tried to figure out for the past few days. I've even read every possible solution on Stackoverflow, but nothing works!

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<div id="picture">
   <div class="picture-1"></div>
   <div class="picture-2"></div>
   <div class="picture-3"></div>
</div>
```

And this code in my CSS:

```
#picture {
height: 250px;
border-top: 1px solid #ffefaf;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
clear: both;
}

.picture-1 {
background: transparent url('images/view.png') left top no-repeat;
}

.picture-2 {
background: transparent url('images/plant.png') left top no-repeat;
}

.picture-3 {
background: transparent url('images/view.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

The pictures are in right folder, the names are right, and yet they won't work. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can use your browser developer tools to determine why the images aren't loading.  I recommend installing Firebug for Firefox, and bringing up the Console tab.  There, it will give you a list of errors related to the image paths being incorrect.  Alternatively, you can hit F12 in Chrome to bring up Chrome's developer tools.  Same thing, check the Console tab in the developer tools window ;)

Comment: put it in jsfiddle.. that's the only way we can help you here..

Comment: Also, since you're using relative URLs in your CSS file, your CSS file location matters.  `/images/plant.png` will be relative to your website URL like `yoursite.com/images/plant.png`.  `images/plant.png` is relative to your CSS file location.  Your CSS file will have to be located in the folder containing your IMAGES folder.

Comment: Heya! Yes, I am using firebug, yet I still can't figure out what's causing the problem. The code should be alright, yet something is affecting it.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in Firebug?  If not, then your images are loading correctly.  If you can't see them, it's probably because the `DIV` you assigned the images to have no height or width set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture `DIV`s have no dimensions. They do not automatically set their size to the image, like an `IMG` tag does. You need to set this in the CSS using `width:` and `height:`.

Comment: But <div id="picture"> already has a height of 250px? Shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Height is not inherited with DIVs.

Comment: Dear god... Apparently assigning the #picture div a height of 250px is not enough. Like you said, DIV's have no dimension like IMG tags have. I had to separately assign the height and width to each picture. Thank you so much Diodeus and Axel, did not think it would be something this simple (I feel embarrased).

Comment: Give them two class names - one for the image and one for a common set of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your inner divs don't have a size so they try to add the following lines to your css:

```
#picture  > div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#picture div{height: 250px;}`

Js fiddle for your answer-> http://jsfiddle.net/niteshp27/xkLd7/